# JQuery Trim as Text Enters field

Tags: jquery

Hi I have some code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputPageName").keyup(function () {
          var value = $(this).val();
          $("#inputPageHandle").val(value);
    }).keyup();
});
```

Basically I need to create a page handle in a hidden field so when the user type in the PageName field it update the PageHandle field however I want to use jQuery.trim() to remove the spaces that the user my put in the PageName field

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputPageName").keyup(function () {
          var value = $.trim($(this).val());
          $(this).val(value);// <-------
          $("#inputPageHandle").val(value);
    }).keyup();
});
```

EDIT:

maybe you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputPageName").keyup(function () {
          var value = $.trim($(this).val());
          $(this).val(value);// <-------
          $("#inputPageHandle").val(value);
    }).keyup();

    $("#inputPageHandle").keyup(function () {
          var value = $.trim($(this).val());
          $(this).val(value);// <-------
          $("#inputPageName").val(value);
    }).keyup();
});
```

Comment: thanks for that however one field is a display title the other is a database page handle is there any way to trim the value of PageName as this enters PageHandle?